# Output list from ForEach Loop

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a function which gets data from all APs in a given store.

```
Function Get-AllAP {
Write-Verbose "Function Start: Get-AllAP"
Write-Host "Getting all Access Points in Store $Store .."
Write-Host " "
Write-Verbose "Getting all APs for Store $Store"
$storeApReq = "https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails.json?.group=$Store"
Write-Verbose "Making request to $storeApReq"
$Global:apIdListReq = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $storeApReq -method Get -ContentType 'application/json' -headers @{ Authorization = $auth }
$Global:apIdList =  $apIdListReq.queryResponse.entityId
$Global:apIdCount =  $apIdListReq.queryResponse."@count"

Write-Verbose "Found $siteAPCount APs in Sites Database. $apIdCount out of $siteAPCount APs found."
Write-Verbose "Response Received: $apIdList"
$Global:apIdURL =  $apIdListReq.queryResponse.entityId
$Global:apURLs = $apIdListReq.queryResponse.entityId | ForEach-Object -MemberName '@url'
Write-Verbose "Looping through APs."

$Global:apLoop = ForEach($apURL in $apURLs) {
$apFullReq = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $apURL'.json' -Method Get -ContentType 'application/json' -headers @{ Authorization = $auth }
Write-Verbose "Response: $apFullReq"

$Global:allApData = $apFullReq.queryResponse.entity.accessPointDetailsDTO



## Format ALL AP data
$apStatus =$allApData.status
$apName = $allApData.name
$apPing = $allApData.reachabilitystatus

## Format data

Write-Host $apName
Write-Verbose $apStatus
Write-Verbose $apPing

## Output data
Write-Host " "
Write-Host "AP Name: $apName"
Write-Host "AP Status: $apStatus"
Write-Host "AP Ping: $apPing"



}

## Clear 
## Give option to reset AP
$doReset = Read-Host "Type 'reset' to reset all Access Points in Store $Store"

IF($doReset-eq 'reset') {
Manage-APResetStore
} else {
Repeat
}
```

After this function is run, the user is given a choice to `Repeat` or reset using `Manage-APResetStore` which is as follows;

```
Function Manage-APResetStore {
Write-Verbose "Function started: Manage-APResetStore"
## Create our batch job
ForEach($apName in $allAPData) {
Write-Host $apName
}

## Send our job
}
```

This is what it outputs currently, which shows the full JSON for `$allAPData` rather than `$apName`.

```
VERBOSE: Function started: Manage-APResetStore
Establishing SSH connection to Cisco Controller dc1flexwlc02
@{@displayName=16162527426; @id=16162527426; adminStatus=ENABLE; apType=AP3500I; cdpNeighbors=; clientCount=3; clientC
ount_2_4GHz=0; clientCount_5GHz=3; ethernetMac=50:57:a8:a1:7c:38; ipAddress=10.0.126.69; locationHierarchy=Dicks Sport
ing Goods > 0026 > 1st floor; macAddress=5c:50:15:1c:43:30; mapLocation=default location; model=AIR-CAP3502I-A-K9; nam
e=0026AP5; reachabilityStatus=REACHABLE; serialNumber=FTX1611E55H; softwareVersion=8.5.131.0; status=CLEARED; type=Uni
fiedAp; unifiedApInfo=; upTime=68916194}
VERBOSE: Function start: Check-DevMode
VERBOSE: Function Start: Execute-Application
```

What the `Manage-APResetStore` function is meant to do is send a list of "reset" commands to the controller for every AP that exists in that store. So what I want to do, is make a list out of my `ForEach` loop that I can use to generate a batch job to send to the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to loop through again after the data is formatted, I created a new array with just the `apName` objects so we can use it in other functions.

Create the array outside the loop:

```
## Create array object
$apArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
```

Add the `apName` object to the array:

```
## Format ALL AP data
$apStatus =$allApData.status
$apName = $allApData.name
$apPing = $allApData.reachabilitystatus

## Format data

Write-Output $apName
Write-Output $apStatus
Write-Output $apPing

## Output data to array
$apArray.Add($apName)
}

Write-Host $apArray
## Clear 
## Give option to reset AP
$doReset = Read-Host "Type 'reset' to reset all Access Points in Store $Store"
```

Using the array:

```
## Loop through our commands
ForEach($apName in $apArray) {
$stream.WriteLine("show loginsessions $apName")
sleep 1
$stream.WriteLine('y')
sleep 2
$stream.Read()


Write-Host "$apName has been reset"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your ForEach section as follows:

```
ForEach ($apName in $allApData.ApName)
```

This will mean that $apName within the loop is just the apName property, and not the entire part of $allApData.